# Create 4x2 grid mosaic

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-editor, codec, transcoding

trying to create a 4x2 grid from 8 videos using the terminal on a mac. The code I am using is not working:

`ffmpeg -i input0.mov -i input1.mov -i input2.mov -i input3.mov -i input4.mov -i input5.mov -i input6.mov -i input7.mov -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v][2:v][3:v] [4:v] [5:v][6:v][7:v] xstack=inputs=8:layout=0_0|0_h0|w0_0|w0_h0|w0+w1_0|w0+w1_h0|w0+w1+w2_0|w0+w1+w2_h0[v]” -map "[v]" 4x2grid.mp4`
Any ideas? I'm using ffmpeg version 4.3.1. And the error message is: 
 *dquote>* 
Not sure why this is. I am relatively new to ffmpeg but can successfully create a 3x2 grid using the following code without the same message: 
`ffmpeg -i input0.mov -i input1.mov -i input2.mov -i input3.mov -i input4.mov -i input5.mov -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v][2:v][3:v] [4:v] [5:v] xstack=inputs=6:layout=0_0|w0_0|0_h0|w0_h0|w0+w3_0|w0+w3_h0[v]" -map "[v]" 3x2grid.mp4`
I have also tried various other possibilities including the following code but with the same result: 
`ffmpeg -i input0.mov -i input1.mov -i input2.mov -i input3.mov -i input4.mov -i input5.mov -i input6.mov -i input7.mov -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v][2:v][3:v][4:v][5:v][6:v][7:v] xstack=inputs=8:layout=0_0|w0_0|0_h0|w0_h0|w0+w3_0|w0+w3_h0|w0+w3+w4_0|w0+w3+w4_h0[v]” -map "[v]" 4x2grid.mp4`
Although I have tried to read the explanation here: 
http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#xstack 
I am not sure I fully understand how to specify the desired layout configuration.

Comment: What ffmpeg version? What is actual error? What is ffmpeg command output?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I've tried to answer your questions and added a greater explanation of the problem and the solutions I've tried. Hope it's clearer. I'm not sure what you mean by ffmpeg command output? Do you mean desired output. If so that is outputting the finished video as an .mp4

Comment: Still missing error message output of ffmpeg.

Comment: @Paul Thanks for your response. Not sure how I find the error message output of ffmpeg? When I try the code discussed above using terminal in Mac OS 10.14.6 I receive the message "dquote" which I gather means I've executed a line of code with only one double-quote character. However as I mention I can create a 3x2 grid using a similar format:  
```ffmpeg -i input0.mov -i input1.mov -i input2.mov -i input3.mov -i input4.mov -i input5.mov -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v][2:v][3:v] [4:v] [5:v] xstack=inputs=6:layout=0_0|w0_0|0_h0|w0_h0|w0+w3_0|w0+w3_h0[v]" -map "[v]" 3x2grid.mp4```

Comment: Please consult wiki page for xstack filter on http://trac.ffmpeg.org, your all inputs must have same size and that probably is erroring out that you ignore.

Comment: That's possible. will have a look at the link. Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have tried it on the colab, plz check if
https://colab.research.google.com/gist/xer-rex/90c426cd7dbdfd4ec3330a7c3b46f98f/sidebyside.ipynb helps?

Comment: Many thanks for your suggestion which looks very interesting. Unfortunately I have no knowledge of Python and can only use ffmpeg using the terminal

Comment: My suggestion on colab has nothing to do with Python, i treat it as a Linux terminal, as you see i did !ffmpeg with exclamation mark at front, i can do !ls, !cp, !rm, ...

Comment: thanks for your response. Sorry, this is a big learning curve! I tried your code substituting my video files and starting with "ffmpeg" not "iffmpeg" but received this message:  
_At least one output file must be specified
zsh: command not found: -filter_complex_  
I assume there will be many formatting issues because I am using ffmpeg on a mac terminal?

Comment: I think it's just the matter of ffmpeg version on colab it uses 

ffmpeg version 3.4.8-0ubuntu0.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers